# Problem with Ansible host groups and filtering IPs

Tags: ansible, vagrant

I am having issues with looping over a list of hosts in an Ansible group, I get the values that I want but I get the spurious error, which I just cant figure out. Would have thought if there was an error it should not print the values at all:

```
fatal: [worker01]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'ansible_eth1'\n\nThe error appears to be in 'roles/vagrant/tasks/main.yml': line 15, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- debug:\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Extract from vagrant file

```
ansible.groups = {
            "workers" => ["worker01", "worker02", "worker03"],
            "controllers" => ["controller01", "controller02"],
            "kubernetes" => ["kubernetes"],
            "all_groups:children" => ["workers", "controllers", "kubernetes"]
        }
```

Sample Host definition used by vagrant

```
{
  "name": "worker03",
  "alias": "worker03",
  "box": "bento/ubuntu-18.04",
  "memory": 2048,
  "vcpu": 2,
  "provider": "virtualbox",
  "autostart": "false",
  "cpus": 2,
  "cpu_percentage": 100,
  "Controller": "SATA Controller",
  "lv_disks": 4,
  "pv_size": 5,
  "infra_ip_addr": "10.2.15.60",
  "service_ip_addr": "10.96.0.60",
  "pod_ip_addr": "192.168.0.60",
  "port_forwards": {},
  "project": "wks",
  "tags": "all",
  "group": "workers",
  "extra_vars": {}
}
```

Following code:

```
- debug:
    msg: "External: {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_eth1']['ipv4']['address'] }} ; Service: {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_eth3']['ipv4']['address'] }} "
  with_items:
    - "{{ groups['workers'] }}"
```

Produces Output - Note error 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'ansible_eth1'

```
ok: [worker01] => (item=worker01) => {
    "msg": "External: 10.2.15.40 ; Service: 192.168.0.40 "
}
fatal: [worker01]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'ansible_eth1'\n\nThe error appears to be in 'roles/vagrant/tasks/main.yml': line 15, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- debug:\n  ^ here\n"}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
worker01                   : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: While you're at it, have a look at `debug: msg="{{ groups['workers'] }}"` I suspect you have an entry in there with value `HostVarsVars`. If I'm right, you then have to find where it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

On modern Ubuntu images, the interface names are goofy (`enp0s31f6` and `wlp0s20f3` for example); what you'll want is to use `ansible_default_ipv4` instead of naming a specific interface (or, of course, you could further loop through all the discovered interfaces but for what you're doing, that doesn't appear to be what you want)

```
- debug:
    msg: "External: {{ hostvars[item]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }} ; Service: {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_eth3']['ipv4']['address'] }} "
  with_items:
    - "{{ groups['workers'] }}"
```

While that will solve your *specific* problem, the more general advice for your future debugging help is to use `debug: var=hostvars` in order to look at what values **are** available, since the error 
`'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'ansible_eth1'` could not possibly be more explicit as to what is wrong.